# Matching zero or more characters in sed

Tags: regex, bash, unix, sed

I was practicing some commands using sed when I was confused by the output of the following command:

```
echo 'first:second' | sed 's_[^:]*_(&)_g'
```

My question is: Why would this command only wrap the string "first" and "second" in parentheses?

Shouldn't the colon be wrapped too since I specified "**zero** or more non-colons" in my regex condition?

Please clarify.

Comment: The colon itself is neither "zero non-colons" (since it is a string of length 1) nor "more non-colons" (since it is a colon), so clearly the pattern does not match.

Comment: What result would you have expected, exactly? It sounds like you expect `(first)(:)(second)`, but that's obviously not going to happen. Or did you mean `(first)():(second)()`?

Comment: Hi chris. Thank you for your enlightenment. I understand the meaning of the code now!

Answer (score 2):

You use

```
[^:]
```

which searches all characters except `:`.
So what you experience is the normal comportment.